# @media only screen and @media screen query which is the better choice

Tags: css, media-queries

Thanks for the help in advance.I am writing some media queries while searching i saw two syntax of it
like **@media only screen and (max-width:767px)** and **@media screen and (max-width:767px)**.Can anyone tell the difference between two and among these two which is the better one to use

Answer (score 0):

You definitely no longer need to use only. It has been used in the past to prevent old browsers to apply the rule to the entire screen. Basically in the past some browsers were ignoring the breakpoint and applying the rule to the entire screen even if stated. In your case `(max-width:767px)`.